# Detect if the user fills the form with the autofill option of google chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-directive, google-analytics, autofill

If anyone can guide me on how to detect if the user fills the form with the autofill option of google chrome.

I have a directive where each time the user fills in the field and change the blur sends an event to google analytics.

But also I need to detect whether the user has filled the form with the autofill option of chrome and push the data for each of the fields to google analytics.

Part of my directive:

```
element.bind('blur', function (e) {
  if ((e.target.value !== 0) && typeof value !== 'undefined')  {
    if (_.has(ga_data, 'sendEvent')) {
      analyticsService.sendEvent(ga_data.sendEvent);
    }

    if (_.has(ga_data, 'action') && ga_data.action === 'blur') {
      analyticsService.sendEvent(ga_data);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but does chrome autofill (already present when the page is loaded) or autocomplete (gives you options of what to fill in as you start typing)? If it's truly an autofill, you could tie the input to a keyup event and set a flag, if the flag hasn't changed, than they used autofill data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [input-directive src](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/b366f0352abccfe4c4868b5a9e8c0b88659bd1ee/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1169), angular sets up a listener for cases of change, input, paste etc.

And whenever the browser autofills the input element, this listener is called and viewValue is commited through array of $parsers as of here [ngModel directive src](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/24cd70058d081b93061734aec29e05f9e37abb3a/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L671).

So eventually you can avoid additional scope.$watch and just rely on $parsers to send ga track event just on linking phase of each input element with directive. And btw don't forget to destroy you parser func right after first usage (i.e. browser autofill), so it will not spam further on viewValue change.

Here's an example:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('detectPrefill', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: { 
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          function detectPrefill (viewValue) {
            //send GA data
            //...

            // just checking that detectPrefill func is destroyed after first usage                
            viewValue && console.log(viewValue);
            ctrl.$parsers.splice(
              ctrl.$parsers.indexOf(detectPrefill), 
              1
            );
            return viewValue;
          }

          ctrl.$parsers.push(detectPrefill);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the way to detect when Chrome auto-fills a form instead of the user doing it is by detecting the absence of an event having occurred, such as the keyup event. Consider the block of HTML and Javascript below. I have the text input field marked with a data attribute that is initially set to false. If the user fills out anything in the form by typing, then the attribute is set to true. The moment when you record whether or not the user filled out the form is on form submit. Then you can check the fields of the form and see if the user entered the input his or herself.

```
<form onsubmit="dosomething()">
    <label for="somefield"></label>
    <input type="text" id="somefield" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('data-entered', (this.value != '').toString());" data-entered="false" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

The reason why you need to use a keyboard event and send the information when the form is submitted is because you can only tell if auto-fill took place when any of the fields have values even when the user typed nothing in. This part is less about code, and is more about what needs to be done so to take a proper measurement.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it runs only when I submit the form?

What I'm trying to make is that whenever you change the blur of each input fields and this is not 0, then instantly send information to google analytic. I have controlled this part But I have not controlled the part when the users filled the fields with autofill option  and then fired to google analytics each of the information when the blur change and not in the submit event.

Comment: I do not think the blur event is the best choice. What I am expressing is that the best way to detect it, is to note which fields the user actually typed  information into. You can then infer that if the values are there, but the user never typed anything in, then auto-fill must be at work. Because this can happen two ways- either auto-fill puts everything in, or the user types something in and auto-fill does the rest, you need to check all the fields at the moment the user hits the submit button.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann I think the issue is he is relying on a blur event to tell him that something was typed in the field. He wants to react immediately when something is entered in the field (but not while the user is in the middle of typing)

Comment: @Random832 Yes, I understand that. However, it is an invalid measurement of the property to record it on anything other than form submit. For example, if you have a login and password field, the user might type their user name and then Chrome auto-fills the password. In that case, if you mark the form as being manually filled, you just recorded something invalid.

Comment: Also, the only valid way to measure this immediately after an interaction is to measure it by each form field as an individual dimension and then on form submit, record what fields have values that the user did not interact with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two way data binding here and watch the ng model on the form field for changes

```
<form method="post">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="user.fname"/><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="user.lname"/><br />
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email"/><br />
  Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="user.phone"/><br />
  Address: <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="user.address"/><br />
</form>
```

Then inside your angular controller you can do something of this sort.

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('AppController', function($scope){
  $scope.user = { };
  $scope.$watch('user', function(nv, ov){
    console.log(nv);
  }, true);
});
```

There might be some cases that you need to handle though, to prevent sending multiple requests because $watch function will be triggered every time the value in the text field changes.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqbq8h3e/1/) which triggers $watch when any value in a form field changes, be it via autofill or manual entry by user.

Comment: He's not asking how to detect changes, he's asking how to detect if they were made via autofill. If you think the above does, so, some explanation of why is in order.

Comment: **But also I need to detect whether the user has filled the form with the autofill option of chrome and push the data for each of the fields to google analytics.**

The reason he wants to detect autofill is because blur event is not getting triggered using which he is sending data, which can be easily resolved if he uses the `$watch`. Sure some modifications might be required but definitely `$watch` is the way to do it. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqbq8h3e/1/)

Comment: @MikeFeltman No, he is asking how to detect changes _given the fact that his current means of detecting changes doesn't work when autofill is used_. That's subtly different than actually caring whether autofill was used.

Comment: Yes, Abhishek Sarkar already said that. I'd delete the comment since it's not useful by itself, but the responses to it are.